# Is ODataController thread safe?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, thread-safety, odata

Is one instance of ODataController created per request?

I couldn't find any useful answers when I searched this online. People talk about MVC Controllers being thread safe and that Web API is built on top of MVC and therefore its controllers should also be thread safe (one instance created per request). But there is no explicit discussion on whether or not ODataController is thread safe.

My question is: what is the relationship between ODataController and Web API - is the former built on top of the later or is it simply an endpoint of the later. And is ODataController thread safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microsoft's OData implementation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.OData/) sits on top of ASP.NET Web API. It's open source, so you can [browse the source code](https://github.com/OData/WebApi) to learn how it works. [`ODataController`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.odata.odatacontroller(v=vs.118).aspx) derives from [`ApiController`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller(v=vs.118).aspx); it adds no additional state, and very little additional behavior. `ODataController` is thread-safe to the extent that `ApiController` is thread-safe.